# typeinfo cause a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, fault, typeinfo

I hava a  segmentation fault. debug with gdb, the first frame in the stack is

in the typeinfo for MyClass()

does someone know something about the typeinfo ?

Comment: Can you paste part of your code that deals with `typeinfo` or `typeid`?

Comment: and you're not compiling `-fno-rtti` are you?

Comment: the code in my company's computer,and this seg fault happend sometimes,now every time . and no -fno-rtti.

Comment: and i'm sure the virtual function has definition. Thank u all

Comment: Well, you are probably passing an invalid pointer to `typeid()`. How does it become invalid - with information you've provided, it's anyone's guess.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem; posting the solution, as it might help someone else:

Making a clean rebuild of the project solved the problem - some of the object files used different versions of a header file and that caused an inconsistency. The actual bug is in my building script, as dependencies are not correctly expressed.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the typeinfo being the top of the frame is totally a red herring in this case. You need to go up the callstack until you find your own code and look in more detail at that point. Almost certainly you're trying to get typeinfo from a null pointer but it's somewhat possible it's just a garbage pointer value (which would be less obvious).

Answer (score 1):

RTTI only applies to classes with at least a virtual method, so make sure you have one.

Also, remember that you can use RTTI directly (dynamic_cast, typeinfo, typeid) ou indirectly (catch is or can be implemented in terms of dynamic_cast).